# CSS styles not applying to a span in specific div when I try to print page

Tags: html, css, printing

I have simple `html + css` page for printing purpose.
I have 2 columns `<div class="col col-left">` and `<div class="col col-right">`, I have `<span class="tag">` also.
My styles looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    ...
    .col {
        float: left;
        height: 1754px;
    }

    .col-left {
        width: 340px;
        background: #3a4d63;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .col-right {
        width: 880px;
        padding: 30px 10px;
    }

    span.tag {
        background: #00cca1;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: -webkit-inline-box;
        margin-top: 4px;
    }
    ...
<style>
```

My `html` looks like this:

```
...
<div class="col col-left">
    <span class="tag">c#</span>
    <span class="tag">Javascript</span>
</div>
<div class="col col-right">
    <span class="tag">Angular</span>
    <span class="tag">TypeScript</span>
</div>
...
```

And the problem is that when I'm trying to print the page, `span.tag` has it's background color only inside `.col-left` but not inside `.col-right`, pretty weird ha?

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `background: #3a4d63;` to your `col-right` too?

Comment: Hey @Jake thanks for the attention but I found the problem, it's described in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue moving `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` from `.col-left` to `.col`